# How to solve/aproach this in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to build the home page of a Flutter app as seen in the picture link below. It has a circular progress bar and list of dates of the month and then widgets below the Dates widget to record vitals and move to start exercise page.

The issue here is that, I want each of the Date to have a separate percentage circular bar and a separate start exercise widget and record vitals widget.

To explain further, If user clicks on 25Monday, the percentage bar and start exercise bar will show and it will only be for 25thMonday. If user clicks on the next day, a separate percentage bar and start exercise widget will display. This will allow tracking of user's progress in that if user clicks the previous day button, the progress percentage can be 25% and if user clicks today's button, the progress circular bar will show percentage for today.

[Here is the picture of the app I want to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImgsP.png)

Comment: Can you include some code with what you tried so far and why is that not working for you?